# access remote_image_url in nested attributes hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, nested-attributes

I'm trying to build a form for carrierwave's :remote_image_url upload, but I can't get it to upload except in console because I can't figure out how to access the params hash with the remote_image_url from the form.

`Image belongs_to :imageable` and `Post has_many :images, as: :imageable, accepts_nested_attributes_for :images`  The uploader is mounted on Image, and file uploads work just fine.  I can also do a remote_image_url upload in console with `post.images.create(remote_image_url: [link text])`

image.rb

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

new.html

```
<%= form_for(@post, :url => posts_path, html: { multipart: true }, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :images do |image| %>
      <%= image.text_field :remote_image_url %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Params from the form:

```
"post"=>{"images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"remote_image_url"=>" [link text] "}}}
```

I've tried accessing the params in posts_controller manually with `params[:images_attributes]["0"][:remote_image_url], params[:remote_image_url], params[:images_attributes], params[:images_attributes][][:remote_image_url]` and just about everything I can think of, but it either creates an image with null for the file or returns `NoMethodError (undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass)`.  It also feels pretty hackish to try to create the image manually in the controller (which I don't have to do if using file_field for a regular upload), but otherwise it doesn't even try to create an image.

posts_controller.rb

```
def create
    @post = current_user.link_posts.build(link_post_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
          if @post.save
            @post.images.create(remote_image_url: params[:images_attributes]["0"][:remote_image_url])
            flash[:success] = "Post created!"
            redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
          else
            redirect_to new_link_post_path
              flash[:warning] = @post.errors.full_messages.to_sentence.html_safe
          end
          }
      end
  end

  private

  def link_post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content, images_attributes: [:image, :remove_image, :image_cache, :image_post_id, :remote_image_url, :_destroy])
  end
```

Comment: Try `params[:post][:images_attributes][][:remote_image_url]`

Comment: @Pavan that gives me `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))`, but `params[:post][:images_attributes]["0"][:remote_image_url]` did it, thanks!

Comment: Ok try `params[:post][:images_attributes]["0"][:remote_image_url]`